# Safari incorrectly rendering list items

Tags: html, safari

I have an unordered list, somthing like this

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <div>filled with other stuff</div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <div>filled with other stuff</div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <div>filled with other stuff</div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

When I look at the list in Safari, list is displayed wrong and when I inspect the html, I get something like this

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <div>filled with other stuff</div>
  <li>
    <div>filled with other stuff</div>
    <li>
     <div>filled with other stuff</div>
    </li>
  </li>
 </li> 
</ul>
```

Any ideas why that is only happening in Safari?

Comment: Unable to repro in Safari 5.0.2 or Chrome 8 (both use WebKit for rendering HTML).  Are you sure your markup is correct?

Comment: which versions of safari/webkit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your markup is wrong. You can't nest an li in an li without a ul coming first.

If you want to do nested lis you need to start a new ul

```
<ul>
<li>lorem
 <ul>
  <li>ipsum</li>
  <li>dolor</li>
 </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Best not to use divs in the li if you can avoid it (which you **certainly** can) - if you need an li to act like a block add display:block to your css.

Comment: Hi Kron, thanks for anwsering.   What I'm aiming for is to NOT have the LI's nested.  Safari is taking the first example that I gave and turning it in to the second example for an unknown reason.

Comment: Oh sorry I should have read the question better. Why are you using divs in your lis? Does it render as expected if you remove them? Also - can you post the rest of your code? It may well be something further up the code